# Table not taking width of container CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout: a jstree on the left and a table to the left with some input fields. However, I want the table does not take the whole width of the containing div.  Here is my code:

```
<div id="container" role="main">
    <div id="tree"></div>
    <div id="data">
        <div class="content" style="text-align:center;">
            <table style="border:1px solid #000;width:100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>Label </Label></td>
                        <td><input id="label" name="label" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>Description </Label></td>
                        <td><textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>Detail </Label></td>
                        <td><textarea id="detail" name="description" type="text"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>condition.disable.link </Label></td>
                        <td><input id="disable-link" name="disable-link" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><Label>condition.hide </Label></td>
                        <td><input id="hide" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have:

```
width=100%;
```

and is

```
width:100%;
```

Change `=` to `:`

**HTML**

```html
<div id="container" role="main">
    <div id="tree"></div>
    <div id="data">
        <div class="content" style="text-align:center;">
          <table style="border:1px solid #000;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
          <tr><td><Label>Label </Label></td><td><input id="label" name="label" type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td><Label>Description </Label></td><td><textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea></td></tr>
          <tr><td><Label>Detail </Label></td><td><textarea id="detail" name="description" type="text"></textarea></td></tr>
          <tr><td><Label>condition.disable.link </Label></td><td><input id="disable-link" name="disable-link" type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td><Label>condition.hide </Label></td><td><input id="hide" type="text"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your width as width:100%

```html
<div id="container" role="main">
    <div id="tree"></div>
    <div id="data">
        <div class="content" style="text-align:center;">
          <table style="border:1px solid #000;width:100%;">
            <tbody>
          <tr><td><Label>Label </Label></td><td><input id="label" name="label" type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td><Label>Description </Label></td><td><textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea></td></tr>
          <tr><td><Label>Detail </Label></td><td><textarea id="detail" name="description" type="text"></textarea></td></tr>
          <tr><td><Label>condition.disable.link </Label></td><td><input id="disable-link" name="disable-link" type="text"></td></tr>
          <tr><td><Label>condition.hide </Label></td><td><input id="hide" type="text"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```